# Why group by requires all non aggregate columns

Tags: sql, group-by

In sql, this query has invalid syntax:

```
select country,city, sum(income) from table1 group by country.
```

Because the group by expects country and city, not just country.
But why is this the case? Because it is possible that I want the result to be grouped by country only. So in below table:

```
country   city            income

canada    toronto          100
canada    montreal          100
us        LA               200
us        NY               300
```

If I want to output:

```
country   city           sum( income)

canada    toronto          200
canada    montreal          200
us        LA               500
us        NY               500
```

What should be my group by clause?

Comment: `group by country, city`.  However, why do you need to aggregate the data if you have only one row per country/city combination?

Comment: If i use group by country,city, then the output will be the same as input, because of the reason you mentioned: only one row per country/city combo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Sql Server you can do this

```
select 
  country,
  city, 
  sum(income) over (partition by country)
from 
  table1
```

Or if you are using another database you can use a sub query

```
  select 
      t1.country,
      t1.city, 
      (select sum(t2.income) from table1 t2 where t1.country = t2.country)
    from 
      table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks. In second case, we don't need a group by clause?

Comment: @Victor - no, you don't need a group by clause, because you are not aggregating the results, you are just "adding" an additional column

Comment: +1 . . . I'm impressed by your ability to understand the question.